# How can I test a click event which changes a useState state with enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { Button, ThirteenBold } from "@selfdecode/sd-component-library";
import { PlayIcon } from "assets/icons";
import { TourButtonProps } from "./interfaces";
import { WelcomeVideoModal } from "../../modals/welcome-video-modal";

/**
 * The tour button.
 */
export const TourButton: React.FC<TourButtonProps> = (props) => {
  const [isIntroVideoShowing, setIsIntroVideoShowing] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <WelcomeVideoModal
        isOpen={isIntroVideoShowing}
        onClickX={() => setIsIntroVideoShowing(false)}
        data-test="tour-button-welcome-video"
      />

      <Button
        {...props}
        width={["max-content"]}
        variant="tour"
        onClick={() => setIsIntroVideoShowing(true)}
        data-test="tour-button"
      >
        <ThirteenBold
          mr={["12px"]}
          color="cl_blue"
          width={["max-content"]}
          letterSpacing={["1px"]}
          display={["none", "block"]}
          textTransform="uppercase"
        >
          welcome tour
        </ThirteenBold>

        <PlayIcon style={{ height: "30px", fill: "#4568F9" }} />
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};
```

And the test coverage report is complaining that I am not testing both of the onClick events, which change the state.

I've tried two approaches, and both fail.
Approach one was to mock the `useState` and see if it gets called as I'd have expected it.
This was the test I tried:

```
 const setState = jest.fn();
 const useStateMock: any = (initState: any) => [initState, setState];
 jest.spyOn(React, "useState").mockImplementation(useStateMock);
 
 const button = wrapper.find(`[data-test="tour-button"]`);
 expect(button).toHaveLength(1);
 button.simulate("click");
 expect(setState).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

This shouldn't even be the final test, as it doesn't check what was the valuee it was called with, but still, it failed because useState wasn't even called.

The second approach I've tried was to check the prop value on this component:

```
 <WelcomeVideoModal
    isOpen={isIntroVideoShowing}
    onClickX={() => setIsIntroVideoShowing(false)}
    data-test="tour-button-welcome-video"
 />
```

And this is the test I've tried

```
  test("Check the isIntroVideoShowing changes to true on buton click", () => {
    jest.spyOn(React, "useState").mockImplementation(useStateMock);
    const button = wrapper.find(`[data-test="tour-button"]`);
    const welcomeVideo = wrapper.find(
      `[data-test="tour-button-welcome-video"]`
    );
    expect(button).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(welcomeVideo.prop("isOpen")).toEqual(false);
    button.simulate("click");
    expect(welcomeVideo.prop("isOpen")).toEqual(true);
  });
```

This one failed claiming it was called with false even after the click.

Is there a way to make these work? Or a different approach to cover these?

Comment: After simulate, try `wrapper.update()` and access the property

Comment: @SarunUK that did it! I've updated the wrapper, than re-set `welcomeVideo` and it passed. Add it as an answer and I'll approve it

Comment: You should **not** mock useState. You don't own the React API - test the observable outcome of the state changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give `wrapper.update` for updating the template with state changes after simulating the click event.

```
test("Check the isIntroVideoShowing changes to true on buton click", () => {
    jest.spyOn(React, "useState").mockImplementation(useStateMock);
    const button = wrapper.find(`[data-test="tour-button"]`);
    const welcomeVideo = wrapper.find(
      `[data-test="tour-button-welcome-video"]`
    );
    expect(button).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(welcomeVideo.prop("isOpen")).toEqual(false);
    button.simulate("click");
    wrapper.update();
    expect(welcomeVideo.prop("isOpen")).toEqual(true);
  });
```

Reference - https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html

Comment: I actually had to re-set welcomeVideo to make it work (otherwise it had the previous prop value), but this approach was how I got it to work. Thank you!

Comment: glad that it helped :)